# Conditional rendering: component or data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make editor functionality for page with Vue2.
On a page there is a 'editable' filter. It recieves content_id. Using this content_id we should recieve data from root Vue instance (for example pageContent.mainTitle). Depending on editModeOn root variable we should render  component or just output appropriate (for example `<editable content="mainTitle" />` or content in mainTitle key).

Skeleton of HTML:

```
<div id="root">
    {{ 'mainContent' | editable }}

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="editModeOn">
        Switch edit mode
    </label>
</div>
```

And a Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        editModeOn: true,
        pageContent: {
            mainTitle: "Test title",
            mainContent: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At, et!"
        }
    },
    filters: {
        editable(contentId) {
            if (!this.editModeOn) {
                return `<editable content="{{ this.pageContent[contentId] }}" />`;
            } else {
                return this.pageContent[contentId];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The reason why I'm trying to achieve that functionality using filters is because of when edit mode disabled I don't want to make any wrapper like span or div (as it nesessary as root instance of any component).

Maybe it's a better way to achieve nesessary functionality, but I didn't find it. Has anyone an idea how to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can solve this with a `template`. A template tag is not rendered.

```
<div id="root">
    <template v-if="!editModeOn">
      {{pageContent['mainContent']}}
    </template>
    <editable v-else :content="pageContent['mainContent']" />

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="editModeOn">
        Switch edit mode
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that will work, but I'm trying to make simple to use component (something like `<editable content_id="mainTitle" />` or `{{ 'mainContent' | editable }}` and not to add huge constructions inserting that component.

Comment: Do you not need matching tags for v-if and v-else?

Comment: @bashkovpd I guess it's still not clear to me what you want.

Comment: OK, maybe I formulated too complex and implemented not the best way. My goal to achieve is to make simple to use editor component, which willn't make extra component root wrappers (like div). I was thinking to make it with filters... but now I can see that it's imposible.

Comment: @bashkovpd Something like this? https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/jGyLMN?editors=1010

Comment: Yep, I'll reformat it a little but I think it's work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the html, the contentId is hard-coded into the div, so I presume you'd have many such divs on the page. I'd make a component and pass in 'content' attribute.
Switching between edit and display can be with v-show

```
Vue.component('editable', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div v-show="!editModeOn">{{ content }}</div>
      <div v-show="editModeOn">
        <input :value="content" @input="$emit('update:content', $event.target.value)"></input>
      </div>

      <label class="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" v-model="editModeOn">
        Switch edit mode
      </label>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['content'],
  data {
    editModeOn: false
  }
})
```

On the main page

```
<editable :content.sync="pageContent['mainTitle']"></editable>    
<editable :content.sync="pageContent['mainContent']"></editable>
```

or perhaps

```
<editable v-for="item in pageContent" content.sync="item"></editable>
```

Some notes:

Using v-show instead of v-if means the user can toggle back and forth between show and edit as desired, v-show keeps the edit in memory between mode but v-if destroys the edit node.

Using the ***.sync*** modifier allows the edits to be passed up to the parent, see [.sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier)

<s>I haven't tested this, so it may need some tweaking, but you get the idea.</s>
See working example [codepen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/YrNQoE)